# ssh many users to one home

Tags: unix, ssh, ssh-keys

I want to allow some trusted users to scp files into my server (to an specific user), but I do not want to give these users a home, neither ssh login.

I'm having problems to understand the correct settings of users/groups I have to create to allow this to happen.

I will put an example;

Having:

1. `MyUser@MyServer`
2. `MyUser` belongs to the group `MyGroup`
3. MyUser's home will be lets say, `/home/MyUser`
4. `SFTPGuy1@OtherBox1`
5. `SFTPGuy2@OtherBox2`

They give me their `id_dsa.pub`'s and I add it to my `authorized_keys`

I reckon then, I'd do in my server something like

`useradd -d /home/MyUser -s /bin/false SFTPGuy1` (and the same for the other..)

And for the last, `useradd -G MyGroup SFTPGuy1` (then again, for the other guy)

I'd expect then, the SFTPGuys to be able to `sftp -o IdentityFile=id_dsa MyServer` and to be taken to MyUser's home...

Well, this is not the case... SFTP just keeps asking me for a password.

Could someone point out what am I missing?

Thanks a mil,

f.

> **EDIT**: Just became aware of ServerFault and [re-opened there](https://serverfault.com/questions/148125/ssh-many-users-to-one-home).

Comment: This is a great question, but it would be more appropriate for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: hey! Sorry, I'm new here, wasn't aware of ServerFault. Moving over there. cheers!

Comment: I wish people would stop saying "belongs on server fault". Why? Because a lot of people will go open a whole new question there, rather than just waiting for the existing one to be migrated. Then we end up shipping an exact duplicate over to SF. Rest assured, if it belongs there .. just wait a few minutes, it will quickly be migrated :)

Comment: Aw.. damn.. didn't know that either. already opened the replica there.
should maybe just delete it from here? the best is probably hope the mods will read these comments and so whatever they find suited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `authorized_keys` readable for them (for the group MyGroup)?

Comment: Well, it wasn't (it was 700), but then I changed the permissions of the .ssh dir and the auth file to 750 though still no effect. Guess it's worth mentioning that my home dir ( `/home/MyUser`) is also readable for the group; most dirs being 750 and the specific folder where they'd drop files is 770.

Nevertheless, about the auth file, I reckon the authentication would be performed by the local user on `MyServer`, isn't it? if so, I don't understand the need for other users to read it... well.. just wondering.